# Unable to get a JOIN work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables. 1st table contains bus information. 2nd table is multi-values and contains **ALL** the stations for the above mentioned bus, where the bus will stop to drop/pick passengers.

**Problem Statement**

Suppose there are two buses **b1** and **b2** with same destination. If a user selects station **s1**, I want both above buses to be shown. Below is the table structure and the query that I am using (query sometimes works but other times not)

**Table Designs**

```
Table 1 
=======
BusId Source Destination DepartureTime

Table 2
=======
BusId StationName ArrivalTime DepartureTime

SELECT 
  b.BusId, b.BusNo, b.Source, b.Destination, b.SrcDepartureTime 
  AS SrcDepTime, b.DstArrivalTime AS DstArrTime, bs.StationName,
  bs.ArrivalTime AS StationArrTime, bs.DepartureTime AS StationDepTime,
FROM 
  Buses b, BusStations bs 
WHERE (b.BusId = bs.BusId) AND (b.Source = **passenger_source** OR bs.StationName = **passenger_source** OR bs.StationName = **passenger_dest**) AND ((DATE(b.SrcDepartureTime) = '2015-10-17') AND (DATE(bs.DepartureTime) = '2015-10-17')) GROUP BY bs.BusId;
```

As I said, query sometimes works but mostly not. What am I doing wrong?? Thanks for any input.

Comment: where you to load a sample in sqlfiddle, we would have the real design and some data to play with

Comment: also you have 3 questions with answers to them over the last year or so. Seems like you either didn't bring them to an Answered Green Check Mark status, or complete your thoughts as to why they didn't work, or whatever. That's how we roll here

Comment: You are using a `group by` and yet most of the column in the `SELECT` don't have aggregation functions.  Hence, you get indeterminate values.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the following:

My scenario is person departing from station x and wants to go to destination y then show all buses that stop at station x and go to destination y at the specified time.

I have used the same column names so should be easy to see what I have done.

```
declare @goingto as nvarchar(50)
declare @goingfrom as nvarchar(50)
declare @time as datetime

set @goingto = 'Basingstoke'
set @goingfrom = 'Winchester'
set @time = '2015-10-17 18:50:00.000'

select i.BusID,i.Source,i.Destination,s.StationName,s.DepartureTime from BusInfo i
left join BusStops s on i.BusID = s.BusID
where i.Destination = @goingto and s.StationName = @goingfrom 
and s.DepartureTime = @time
```

Data:

```
Table Bus Info
1   Southampton Basingstoke 2015-10-17 00:00:00.000
2   Portsmouth  Basingstoke 2015-10-17 00:00:00.000
3   Bristol          Winchester 2015-10-16 00:00:00.000
4   Winchester  Bristol         2015-10-16 00:00:00.000


Table Bus Stops

1   Winchester  2015-10-17 12:00:00.000 2015-10-17 18:50:00.000
1   Basingstoke 2015-10-17 19:00:00.000 2015-10-17 19:10:00.000
1   RedBridge   2015-10-17 21:00:00.000 2015-10-17 21:10:00.000
2   Winchester  2015-10-17 12:00:00.000 2015-10-17 18:50:00.000
3   Basingstoke 2015-10-17 19:00:00.000 2015-10-17 19:10:00.000
2   Southampton 2015-10-17 17:50:00.000 2015-10-17 18:50:00.000
```